# How to Conditionally Remove the Password Attribute from the ServiceInstall Element in WiX Toolset

Tags: xml, wix, wix3, wix3.11

I need to conditionally remove the Password attribute in the ServiceInstall element in the WiX Toolset.  The problem I'm trying to solve is this.  I have a service to install and we support Group Managed Service Accounts.  For gMSA, there is no password requirement and including the password, even an empty password, results in a failed installation.  Removing the password attribute in the ServiceInstall element allows the installation using gMSA to be successful.  The problem is, we also support non-gMSA, so in all other situations the Password attribute is required.

I currently have a solution that works, but I'm not happy with it.  My current solution is to create two separate component files in WiX and then call the correct file based on if the installation is coming from gMSA or not.  I don't like this because the two component files are identical outside of the Password attribute so I'm duplicating the rest of the file.

I've looked into using the utils schema, and specifically something like the [XmlFile](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/util/xmlfile/)  or [XmlConfig](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/util/xmlconfig/) elements, but this doesn't seem to be the correct use case.  I've also thought of using the [extensions](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/wixdev/extensions/extensions/) schema, but I'm unsure of how to go that route.  I thought maybe I could use the compiler extension to parse through the XML of a ServiceInstall element and remove the Password attribute if there is a value.  The problem is I don't even know if that's possible, and if it is, where to begin as I'm just starting to explore that area.